# Get Current Category details in Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to fetch current category details.
For example, if the route is example.com/articles/category-slug

In my ArticleCategory Model

```
public function article(){
      return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
  }
```

In Article Model

```
public function category(){
         return $this->belongsTo(ArticleCategory::class, 'category_id');
    }
```

Routes

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'articles'], function(){
      Route::get('/', 'Frontend\ArticleController@index')->name('articles.index');
      Route::get('/{articlecategory}', 'Frontend\ArticleController@category');
      Route::get('/{articlecategory}/{slug}', 'Frontend\ArticleController@show');
    });
```

ArticleController

```
public function category(Request $request, ArticleCategory $articlecategory)
 {
   $category = $articlecategory->id;
   $currentcategory = ArticleCategory::where('id', $category)->first();
   return $currentcategory;
 }
```

i have created two categories, 1. Updates 2. News

When i go to the url `example.com/articles/updates` i receive a error `"Page Not Found"`

When i change the `{{ articlecategory }} to {{ category }}` only in the routes file. It shows a blank page without the current category details. How to solve this?

Note: I used the same code earlier in Laravel 5.5 and it worked well. In Laravel 5.6 i see this error. I'm already using a cache killer on chrome and have also cleared cache and views in laravel as suggested by few links on google. However i still see the same error

Comment: because route model binding is use `id` to find the records,

Comment: why are you fetching same `ArticleCategory` twice in `category` action. You have already `$articlecategory` object by using type-hint.

Comment: So you mean $currentcategory = $articlecategory; would do the job. I didnt understand

Comment: what you see if go to `example.com/articles/1`

Comment: **Note**: Why are you using querying for `$currentcategory` when it's the smae as `$category`?

Comment: actually he can use 1 line `return $articlecategory;` instead 3 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out a way that worked.

I have changed route key value to slug and it worked. I thought that was done by the slugs package i was using. After adding the below code manually to the models it works as expected.

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
      {
          return 'slug';
      }
```

Comment: 404 becasue this line public function category(Request $request, `ArticleCategory $articlecategory`) , ArticleCategory default use id to find the record, so means where('id', 'slug'), so is not found

Comment: its working now. i just had to change the routekey value.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like model binding to use a database column other than id when retrieving a given model class, you may override the ‍‍`getRouteKeyName` method on the Eloquent model:

for example :

```
class ArticleCategory extends Model
{
    public $table='article_category';

    public function article(){
        return $this->hasMany(Article::class);
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'category_slug';
    }
}
```

and my `article_category` table :

```
| category_slug |   name  | id |
|:-------------:|:-------:|:--:|
|      cat1     | Updates |  1 |
|      cat2     |   News  |  2 |
```

Answer (score 0):

your routes should be :

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'articles'], function(){
      Route::get('/', 'Frontend\ArticleController@index')->name('articles.index')->name('articles');
      Route::get('/{category}', 'Frontend\ArticleController@category')->name('category');
      Route::get('/{category}/{slug}', 'Frontend\ArticleController@show')->name('category_articals');
    });
```

now you are passing a `category_slug` to your controller then

> example:  example.com/articles/news

in your controller :

```
public function category(Request $request,$category)
 {
   $category = ArticleCategory::where('slug',$category)->first();
   if($category){
      // category found , return category to page
      return view('category',compact('category'));
   }else{
      // category not found , return 404 page
      return view('error.404');
   }
 }
```

Comment: I guess when we use {{ articlecategory }} in the route i should have access to the whole article category column related to it. Right? And why this is working with 5.5 and shows error in 5.6 I'm confused